# How To Get Google Event Messages From Pub/Sub service in terminal?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-pubsub

Is there a command to get the `Message body` as shown in the Google Cloud Platform Console Subscriptions (relating to event triggers from Nest Doorbell Device) in the terminal?

If not, how can I make an API request to the Pub/Sub service and receive the same JSON Payload shown in the GCP Console?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the gcloud CLI to view subscription messages. Just do not **ack** the message so that it will continue to be delivered to subscribers.

Note: I do not work with the Nest doorbell, so I cannot comment on their interface. The following is specific to the Pub/Sub service.

[gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/pubsub/subscriptions/pull)

You can do the same thing with the REST API or one of the SDKs.

[REST API: Method: projects.subscriptions.pull](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/pull)

[SDK: Receiving messages using Pull](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull)

Comment: For the REST API I am getting a permission denied error, I have added the API key to the URL, I think I need to add OAuth credentials to the POST request but I am unsure on how to do it?

Comment: @john - API keys are not supported, you must use an access token. Create a new question - to answer requires details from you and the steps are too big to put in comments. As a tip, this command will generate the token you need: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/print-access-token Add an HTTP header **Authorization: Bearer TOKEN** to your REST API request.

Comment: @john - Also read this link that discusses IAM Pub/Sub authorization: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control

Comment: i have posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70961353/proper-way-of-authorizing-google-pub-sub-rest-api-post-request