# Proper way of Authorizing Google Pub/Sub REST API POST Request

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am attempting to retrieve event messages from Google pub/sub.

I have tried the following request:

`curl -XPOST -H 'Authorization: Bearer ya29AuthToken' -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{'returnImmediately': false, maxMessages: 10}' 'https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projectID/subscriptions/projectName:pull?key={APIKEY}'`

I receive the following response from the server

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "User not authorized to perform this action.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

What am i doing wrong with this? The API Key is correct and the auth token has not expired.

Comment: 1) Is Pub/Sub enabled in your project? **gcloud services list**. 2) Do you have an IAM role granting you permission? Edit your question and list the roles granted to your identity. Check if your identity has the role **roles/pubsub.subscriber**, **roles/pubsub.editor** or **roles/editor**. There are other roles that also grant the required permissions. In summary, you need the permission **pubsub.subscriptions.consume** to pull messages.

Comment: Also, delete the APIKEY from the query. API Keys are not supported for authorization.

Comment: Pub/Sub is enabled, I am currently receiving the messages in my GCP Subscription Console. The only account/role in permissions is owner, do I need to add specific permission to the owner account?

Comment: Also I am wondering how the request is tied to an account if I am making the request using a call from my terminal? I feel as if I may have missed a step in configuration

Comment: The identity that I am referring to is the one used by the command that generated the token. Since the role **Owner** has the required permission, there is something else that needs investigation.

Comment: Review the documentation on how to set up the CLI **gcloud**. Start with **gcloud auth list**

Comment: @JohnHanley I removed the API key from my request and got the error `403 permission denied, request missing valid API Key`. I will look through the documentation again. Thank you for the direction.

Comment: That error means that the **Authorization** header and/or token value is wrong, incorrect formatted, etc.

Comment: Use these commands to make sure you are generating a valid token: **gcloud auth application-default login** and **gcloud auth application-default print-access-token**. then update your question with the actual command you used masking the token value.

Comment: Note: There is a syntax error in your curl command **-XPOST**. It should be **-X POST**.

Comment: Whoops, fixing that gave me a new error message: `code: 403 message: "Request had insufficient authentication scopes."` It's clear that it's an auth issue, do you think I misstepped when setting up the initial OAuth?

Comment: That means the identity that created the TOKEN does not have the required permissions. Did you run the two commands that I mentioned? How did you create the TOKEN?

Comment: John, could you confirm that what @John Hanley suggested worked, please?

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks John, I was using the OAuth token generated to access my NEST devices, I was able to make the call using `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token.` Does the token always stay the same or will I need to refresh every so often?

Comment: The token expires in 3600 seconds.